# sharing code between UITableViewCell different idenitfiers

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a working `UITableViewCell`. Now I have a different cell I need to make which is exactly like the previous one - but has a UIWebView instead of UIImageView.
I was thinking of doing a different xib for the cell, but the thing is they have tons of code and logic in common (for the rest of the controls)

What is my best approach in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a parent class: put all the common code there, then make 2 subClasses of this superClass, they'll inherit the superClass code, and put there all the code and objects specific for each of them

Comment: and make 2 different xibs? Where do the IBOutlet goes? in the parent class? in each subclass?

Comment: well, if there are differences you need to put in xib, yes, of course... but keep in mind that objects in XIB may reference to property of the parent class too, so you may have a UIView in each XIB that points to a property in parentClass (because it's a common UIView for the 2 classe) and then use different UIView pointing to property in the subClasses